# How do you view a function's documentation with Visual Studio Code's Intellisense?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

I'm writing Javascript with Visual Studio Code on a Mac.

I have this function, documented in JSDoc format:

```
 /**
 * Adds the passed Matter Body to the simulation.
 * @param {Matter.Body} body - The body to add to the physics simulation
 * @param {string} imageUrl - The URL of the image to use to represent this body in the simulation. It should match an image URL that has already been added via loadImages()
 * @param {function} [onCollide] - Optional function to call when this body collides
 */
addObject(body, imageUrl, onCollide) {
```

However, when the Intellisense tooltip pops up it looks like this:

[image]

It's all jumbled up and not showing the full documentation. Is there some sort of key combo I need to press to display the full function documentation in the tooltip?

Comment: Alt+F12 peeks the object definition... Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

In fact it never does, but this is intended:

In cause of the fact, that you don’t have a parameter defined yet, you can read the doc about the first parameter.

If you had written/defined the first parameter and a comma too, you could read the doc about the second one,...

It’s a similar behavior as with c#-methods.

Give it a try...